# json_encode for multi line string php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass a string from php (from mysql) into a variable in javascript which has multiple lines. I understand I need to use php's json_encode() to do this. It's from a textarea and javascript opens a small window and is supposed to write its output. But I can't seem to get past the same error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

I'm guessing there's something else I need to do in the javascript

here's the very simple js function:

```
function view_notes(notes) {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=400,height=400");

 console.log(notes);
  myWindow.document.write(notes);



}
</script>
```

And here's the php:

```
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

 // echo "regulars <br>";
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


      $phone=$row['phone'];
      $formatted_phone=format_phone($phone);
      $notes=$row['notes'];
      $js_notes=json_encode($notes);
      var_dump($js_notes);


      echo"<tr>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['First_Name'];
      echo "</td>";


      //echo "&nbsp";
      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['Last_Name'];
      echo "</td>";
     // echo "&nbsp";


      echo "<td>";
      echo $formatted_phone;
      echo "</td>";
    //  echo "&nbsp";


      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['email'];
      echo "</td>";

      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['court_status'];
      echo "</td>";

      echo "<td>";
      echo "<button onclick=\"view_notes($js_notes)\">View Notes</button>";
      echo "</td>";




      }
      /* free result set */
      $result->free();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't concated the string properly. To solve replace this line

```
echo "<button onclick=\"view_notes($js_notes)\">View Notes</button>";
```

with

```
echo "<button onclick='view_notes(".$js_notes.")'>View Notes</button>";
```

To solve the line break issue create one more javascript function

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    if (typeof str === 'undefined' || str === null) {
        return '';
    }
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

and use above function in your view_notes function like this

```
function view_notes(notes) {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=400,height=400");
  console.log(notes);
  myWindow.document.write(nl2br(notes));
}
```

Comment: this worked! but the line breaks aren't there anymore which is going to make it hard to read. Any idea how to get the line breaks?

Comment: which line breaks?

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the work you put in to helping me

Answer (score 0):

Can you share result of 
 console.log(notes);

Because I think the problem is mismatch of quotes here-
echo "View Notes";
When this evaluates it places $js_notes in double quotes which breack HTML syntex rule.

Go to view source of the page in the browser and inspect this line.

Hope this will help.